# Exporting/Importing data across environments in Oracle with an IDENTITY column

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, export, identity

I have created a table using an IDENTITY clause on a column as seen below:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(
    id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    c1 VARCHAR2 (100),
    c2 VARCHAR2 (100),
    c3 VARCHAR2 (100)
);
```

Then I have inserted a number of rows into this table:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(c1,c2,c3)
VALUES('a','b','c')
INSERT INTO tablename(c1,c2,c3)
VALUES('d','e','f')
...
```

The id column is automatically generated for each row as 1, 2  etc.

I then need to export the table and data and import to a new environment. I export the data as an xls file, create the table in the new environment, and import the data from the xls file.

The data is imported successfully, but when I try to insert a new row I run into an error

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (APPS.SYS_C00453325) violated

I assume this is because the id column is trying to start from 1 again, where a row with id of 1 already exists from the imported data.

Is there a way to make the IDENTITY column continue from the highest id value that was imported?

I realise that importing my data using an INSERT script would resolve this issue. Is it seen as bad practice to export/import data using any other method?

Any advice much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am also finding that the same error occurs even when I use an INSERT script. As the id values are provided during the INSERT, the IDENTITY sequence is never accessed and therefore never incremented. Is it possible to use IDENTITY to continue the sequence from my manually inserted ids?

Comment: Does using data pump to export and import avoid this issue? (I would think so but it isn't something I've tried yet). Otherwise, do you know the highest ID from the source before you create the table in the destination - if so you can specify `start with` for the identify column? (Doesn't work if you'll be repeating this; but inserting new rows in the destination suggests it's a one-off, I think.)

Comment: And the identify column is just a sequence underneath really; you could also identify that and use the usual techniques to reset it to a higher value after the 'import'. Your failing inserts are also incrementing it too, so if you repeat the first new insert it will work eventually... not ideal though!

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'm not familiar with data pump, but I'll definitely look in to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the column's generation properties using [`start with limit value`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877).

```
create table demo1
( id integer generated by default as identity primary key
, dummy varchar2(1) );

insert into demo1 (dummy) select dummy from dual connect by rownum <= 10;

-- 10 rows created.

create table demo2
( id integer generated by default as identity primary key
, dummy varchar2(1) );

insert into demo2 select * from demo1;

-- 10 rows created.

insert into demo2 (dummy) select 'Y' from dual;

-- Fails with ORA-00001: unique constraint (xxx.SYS_C001886275) violated
-- because the identity generator tries to set id = 1, but 1 already exists in the table.

alter table demo2 modify id generated by default as identity start with limit value;

-- Table altered.

insert into demo2 (dummy) select 'Y' from dual;

-- 1 row created.

select * from demo2;

       ID DUMMY
--------- -----
        1 X
        2 X
        3 X
        4 X
        5 X
        6 X
        7 X
        8 X
        9 X
       10 X
       11 Y
```

It might be a good idea at this point to prevent any more manually entered ID values:

```
alter table demo2 modify id generated always as identity;

-- Table altered.

insert into demo2 (id, dummy) values (99, 'Z')
--                 *
-- ERROR at line 1:
-- with ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. To further prevent manually entered ID values, should I ensure my INSERT scripts simply exclude the ID column, and just  let the IDENTITY sequence handle it all?

Comment: Yes you can omit the `ID` column and let the identity mechanism handle it. If you define it as `generated always` instead of `generated by default` then it won't let you specify a value for `ID`.